# Django + Anymail + Mailgun: Scheduling email delivery

Tags: mailgun, django-anymail, django-mailgun

Mailgun supports [scheduling emails at a later date in the future](http://blog.mailgun.com/tips-tricks-scheduling-email-delivery/), but how does one take advantage of this through Anymail?

Anymail provides a wrapper over Mailgun functionality and supports Mailgun-specific features like recipient variables. But how does one access Mailgun's scheduled delivery feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anymail has a [`send_at`](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sending/anymail_additions/#anymail.message.AnymailMessage.send_at) message attribute which normalizes scheduled sending across the ESPs that support it, including Mailgun.